# How can I batch rename folders (cut beginning to end)?

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I have a long list of folders formatted like this:

```
Moscow,_1_November_2021
Khosta,_9_November_2021
Adler,_12_November_2021
```

I would like them to begin with the date and end with location, like this:

```
1_November_2021,Moscow
9_November_2021,Khosta
12_November_2021,Adler
```

How can I batch rename these folders?

Comment: Are you using `bash` or `zsh` in your mac?

Comment: @Fravadona I'm using bash :)

Answer (score 1):

This simple loop should do the job (remove the `echo` once you checked that it does what you want):

```sh
for dir in ./*,_[1-3]*_*_20[0-2][0-9]
do
    name=${dir##*/}
    path=${dir%"$name"}
    echo mv -v "$dir" "$path${name#*,_},${name%%,*}"
done
```

Comment: nothing changes. I tried it with two folders, terminal shows:

    mv -v ./Resselpark,_22_May_2020 ./Resselpark,_22_May_2020


    mv -v ./St.Gallen,_1_July_2020 ./St.Gallen,_1_July_2020

Comment: There was indeed a problem, try it now

Comment: It worked now, thanks a lot! Just one thing, it changed the names in the Terminal, but in the actual folder it still hasn't changed.. what am I doing wrong here? (I already tried without echo)

Comment: changing `echo mv -v "$dir" "$path${name#*,_},${name%%,*}"` to `mv -v "$dir" "$path${name#*,_},${name%%,*}"` (without the echo) doesn't work??

Comment: when I type ls in Terminal, it shows the change (date first, then city), but the actual folder names have not changed, no; However, afterwards I cannot access the pictures and movies anymore, which are in these folders. when I try to move the folders, an error occurs: The operation can’t be completed because one or more required items can’t be found.(Error code -43)

Comment: You may have a serious problem with your disk; is that an external one? how old os the mac?

Comment: Yes, its an external hard drive.  Its a MacBook Air, so a few years old.. also, I just realised with two other operations, that are supposed to create new folders, do not show the created folders

Comment: You should check the S.M.A.R.T attributes of the external disk, for example with https://sourceforge.net/projects/smartmontools/files/smartmontools/

Comment: Thank you! Its working now:)

Comment: I'm glad it worked ;-) What was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

With `ls` and `sed` you can build the commands that you need, with `xargs` you can execute all of them:

```
ls|sed  's/^\(.*\),_\(.*\)$/\0 \2,\1/'| xargs -L1 mv
```